# What is the rule for continuous oscillation of an RF circuit with integrated LC?

Tags: circuit-design, rf, oscillator, oscillation

Circuit simulation software helps out many times from hard mathematical formulas. I designed most of the RF circuits with the help of LTS and Proteus. I have seen that they are good equally, but have sometimes different approaching how the circuit reacts at certain changes.
Recently, I researched on internet for the law of oscillation, but ended up with many theories. As you can guess, I develop RF circuits in practical sense for my own use.

Below is a circuit, I want to develop. I know the formulas of angular frequency of LC tank circuit and I know several oscillators. I have even used many calculators on internet for the parts of RF circuits, but I can not reason that this circuit oscillates in LTS, but not in Proteus. As I predicted before, they are equally good and finally I want to reveal the secret of continuous oscillation. Can you fill out the missing values for the circuit below with mentioning the procedure or reasoning? I want to be independent from use of simulation software.

[image: circuit]

Edit:

This circuit oscillates in LTS, but not in Proteus.

[image: lts]

LTS .asc file:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 4128 680
WIRE 288 -576 80 -576
WIRE 720 -576 288 -576
WIRE 288 -544 288 -576
WIRE 288 -544 256 -544
WIRE 336 -544 288 -544
WIRE 256 -496 256 -544
WIRE 384 -480 336 -480
WIRE 720 -480 720 -576
WIRE 336 -416 336 -432
WIRE 256 -400 256 -416
WIRE 304 -400 256 -400
WIRE 336 -400 336 -416
WIRE 336 -400 304 -400
WIRE 304 -368 304 -400
WIRE 640 -368 640 -432
WIRE 640 -368 304 -368
WIRE 816 -368 640 -368
WIRE 80 -352 80 -576
WIRE 304 -320 304 -368
WIRE 384 -304 384 -480
WIRE 240 -272 80 -272
WIRE 720 -224 720 -400
WIRE 80 -192 80 -272
WIRE 304 -192 304 -224
WIRE 384 -192 384 -240
WIRE 384 -192 304 -192
WIRE 304 32 304 -192
WIRE 80 192 80 -128
WIRE 304 192 304 112
WIRE 304 192 80 192
WIRE 720 192 720 -144
WIRE 720 192 304 192
WIRE 304 336 304 192
FLAG 304 336 0
FLAG 640 -432 antenna
FLAG 816 -368 out
SYMBOL ind 272 -512 M0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMBOL cap 352 -544 M0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 100n
SYMBOL npn 240 -320 R0
WINDOW 3 12 112 Left 2
SYMATTR Value BC547B
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMBOL cap 368 -304 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 330n
SYMBOL res 64 -368 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 47k
SYMBOL voltage 720 -240 R0
WINDOW 123 24 44 Left 2
WINDOW 39 24 72 Left 2
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL cap 64 -192 R0
WINDOW 3 29 49 Left 2
SYMATTR Value 1n
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMBOL res 288 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL cap 352 -480 M0
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value 100n
SYMBOL res 704 -496 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 100
TEXT 768 72 Left 2 !.tran 0 5m 4.9m 10u startup
```

Comment: Oscillators can be tricky in simulation.  Some integration methods (like trapezoidal) have inherent damping, so oscillators may not oscillate with those methods.  If you have a choice in Proteus you can try switching integration methods (to "gear' for example) to see if you get results similar to LTS.  Also, sometimes you have to purposely start the oscillation in simulation by transient stimulation of the circuit.

Comment: I have just switched to GEAR in Proteus, but still no oscillation. TY for your feedback..

Comment: Have you went through the tricks/techniques shown here? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/706082/must-lc-resonant-frequency-be-identical-to-oscillating-frequency-in-rf-circuit/706105#706105

Comment: You need some initial conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of transistor gain you need to add more energy to LC tank than is lost per one oscillation.

Another condition is to add this energy at the right time, in particular section of sine, depends on if it is going about series or parallel tank.

Comment: Can you draw an example of what you are arguing? I hope I can upvote this time, if so. I mean drawing an example filling out the variables for the circuit at the top of my post. TY

Comment: I am sorry, I am on phone right now. But general rule for parallel LC tank is: high L+low C starts oscillate much easier than low L+high C. So start designing with first combination.