# Why Oscillator with amplifier is resulting in damping response?

Tags: rf

I am designing an oscillator and feeding it to a buffer and I can't figure out why there is a loss at the output? When I simulate the oscillator by itself, the amplitude is larger but when I combine it with a buffer, there is a decrease in the amplitude at the output of the buffer? Any tips would be appreciated.

Here is a schematic
[image]
Here is the simulation of the oscillator by itself and of the output when they are combined.

The top picture is the oscillator. Bottom is the output when combined with the buffer (PA with gain ~1).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the effective input resistance of the amplifier, have you measured it? When you say simulating the oscillator alone, did you include this resistance?

Comment: when I simulated the resistance, I cut the wire that connects the output of the oscillator to the decoupling capacitor from the buffer and measure at the collector of the oscillator. How do I measure the effective input resistance of the amplifier? Would it be Beta*((0.026/ic)+RE)?

Comment: This circuit won't work in real life at circa 500 MHz with 2N3904 transistors.

Comment: I can just change the transistor. There are many BJTs with f_T in the GHz range.

Comment: So I know how I can calculate the input impedance. I think it is Beta*((0.026/ic)+RE). After this,  should I create a matching network between the oscillator and input of the transistor? how do I measure the input impedance in LT SPICE?

Comment: You can measure it using the technique shown here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/706082/must-lc-resonant-frequency-be-identical-to-oscillating-frequency-in-rf-circuit/706105#706105

Comment: How did they plot the impedance?

Comment: Don't forget the effect of R4 and R5.

Comment: There's so much wrong with this.  Start by _just_ simulating the amplifier stage, replacing the input with an AC source.  See how much amplification you get -- note: it won't be much, if any.  Your \$\left(\frac {26\mathrm{mV}}{i_c} + R_E \right) \beta\$ approximation is correct at low frequencies, but it starts getting inaccurate at \$\frac{f_T}{A_V}\$ (\$A_V\$ = voltage gain), and you're at about \$f_T\$ for that transistor, so its meaningless.  Basically -- you need to pay attention to the high-frequency model of the transistors.

Comment: I changed the model to one with 8 GHz fT.

Comment: Also, like Kevin White said, I would need to include the parallel effect of R4 and R5  so it would be  ((26mV/ic)+RE)*Beta in parallel with (R4||R5) right?